# Powering Raspberry Pi using DC Power supply

Tags: power-supply

I am trying to power my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ using [this](https://mcs.com.bd/product/dazheng-ps-305d-dc-power-supply-3-digit-0v-30v-0a-5a/) DC power supply. According to the official [FAQ](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/faqs/) the power requirements seems suitable. But, I am not skilled in how to use the power supply to power the Raspberry Pi.

How do I connect the terminals and use some sort of USB converter to connect the Raspberry Pi?

What should be the settings on the power supply?

The reason I went for the power supply was because after trying about a dozen USB power adapters (android chargers), it didn't work and every time the Raspberry Pi powers up, the under voltage sign is displayed.

Hope I explained this properly. Not an electrical engineer so, some guidelines will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why didn't you buy the official power supply? https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply/

Comment: @CoderMike I bought the pi from a local vendor and the official power supply was not available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Raspberry Pi stack exchange.

You can use your power supply with set of cables named USB socket to banana, like one below.
[image: USB to banana]

Plug (a good quality) USB to micro USB cable to power your Raspberry Pi.

Settings: Go for 5.1V on your power supply and around 2.5A current.

[image: PSU settings]

Answer (score 3):

You can grab a micro USB cable (able to be plugged in your Pi) and cut that from USB type-A end and then take out wires' ending from it. It will have four wires- red, black, white and green. Attach or solder red wire to positive terminal of supply and negative terminal to black wire of your USB cable. here you go. Now you can use your Pi.